# Regex_replace from boost library doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex

I am trying remove a substring following a pattern.

I am trying to use the boost library as it provides the regex_replace, which as I understood should replace every occurence of the regex with my given new string.

```cpp
std::string s("m_value[0..3]");
boost::regex rgx("\[.*\]");
return boost::regex_replace(s, rgx, "");
```

This code returns m_value[03] instead of m_value. Any ideas why?

Comment: [Compile with warnings on](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aEDjU1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to escape the escape.

You need two backslashes to add a backslash in strings:

```
boost::regex rgx("\\[.*\\]");
```

Or use raw string literals:

```
boost::regex rgx(R"(\[.*\])");
```

Comment: Of course. It got a little confusing writing regex in a string. Thank you.